# Manage data: users able to sort the data fields to select course

Tags: views

I need to find the right module or set of modules to help visitors to my site review various course offerings. The categories would be presenter name, course name, interest area. Also want to list the course description as a pop up. The user should be able to sort the data (like you would sort from different airline options - price, flight duration, time, stops, etc.)

What do I use? Views? Fields? Data?

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is quite general, you should be able to achieve that with a combination of

1. Content type for the course with relevant [fields](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/field-ui) added.
2. [Comments](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/comment) enabled on the course nodes for the visitor reviews
3. [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to list courses ( exposed filters for user filtering, table display provides column click sort options )
4. You may also want something like [fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) or [rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) for user voting.